# Proving any linear map on a subspace of $V$ can be extended to a linear map on $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose V is a finite dimensional vector space. I am trying to prove that any linear map on subspace of V can be extended to linear map on V.

Basically, showing that if $U$ is a subspace of $V$ and $S \in L(U,W)$, then there exists a $T \in L(V,W)$ such that $Tu=Su$ for all $u \in U$.

I attempted it by taking the basis of the subspace U with Dim(m) and extending it to basis of V with Dim(n). Since mapping of all vectors of basis of W exists and taking the remaining m-n vectors as zero - we will get a linear map to an element that is in V by defining $T \in L(V,W)$ as:

$T(a_1u_1 + ...+ a_mu_m+b_1v_1 + ...+b_nv_n)=a_1Su_1 + ...+a_mSu_m$

Then $Tu=Su \space  \forall u \in U$

What I dont get is this:

1) Please correct me if I'm wrong but a linear map on V should be defined for all elements of V. But does the extension inside $T$ not limit to vectors in V with $v_m+1=.....=v_n=0$ thereby excluding vectors in V where these are not zero?

2) How does the $Su$'s hit every value in $W$?

3) Is there a more intuitive way or step by step explained way of how I need the above equation and condition? I have no idea why it was chosen as thus.

Thanks!

Comment: The map $T'$ (we should give it a new name) is defined for all $v\in V$. It just happens to have uninteresting **values** at $v_{m+1}$ to $v_m$. The **range** (image) of the extension is the same as the range of $T$, which need not be all of $W$. Note that you have (or should have) defined $T'(v_i)$, for $i\gt m$, by $T'(v_i)=0$. and extended by linearity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there's a much easier way to go about this. Let $W$ be a proper subspace of $V$. Then $W$ has a basis $\{w_1,\dotsc,w_k\}$. A standard theorem of linear algebra says this basis for $W$ can be extended to a basis $\{w_1,\dotsc,w_k,v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$ for $V$. Now, let $f:W\rightarrow U$ be a linear map. Then let $\overline{f}(w_i)=f(w_i)$ for $1\leq i\leq k$ and let $\overline{f}(v_i)=\mathbf0$ for $1\leq i\leq n$. Extending linearly gives an extension $\overline{f}:V\rightarrow U$ of $f$ to $V$.

Comment: Hi, do you know why in your answer you didnt have the coefficients but in the answer up above I have the coefficients being the same on both sides? Thanks!

Comment: This is for future readers\self studyers like me looking for an answer to this. I originally thought of this answer myself, but on reflection I don't believe this is a function because it is not necessarily defined for all elements of the domain $V$, take $v\in V\backslash W, w\in W, w\neq 0, f(w)\neq0$ note that $v+w\notin span\{w_1,...,w_k\}, v+w\notin span\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ so,  $\hat{f}(v+w)=?$ For a more concrete example, take $V=\mathbb{R}^2, U=(1,0)$, this extension is the basis element $(0,1)$, by the definition of the function above, what is $\hat{f}((1,0)+(0,1))=\hat{f}(1,1)=?$

Comment: This answer seems easier but is really a more convoluted answer than the poster originally wrote, namely defining $T(\sum a_iv_i+\sum b_iw_i)=S((\sum a_iv_i)$ because it is implicitly does what Brian suggests but the definition immediately deals with pathological examples listed in my comment above which seemed to be swept under the rug with "extend linearly".

Answer (score 4):

The OP, I assume, knows this, but in the interest of making this question more searchable, this is Exercise 3.3 in Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* (as well as the reason I was looking up questions like this).

I can only imagine what grading twenty or thirty proofs for this (and for a few other results) does to one's mind, but apparently my professor didn't find anything wrong with mine (but for a few typographical errors, now corrected).  I'm posting it because, from what I can tell, it differs somewhat from the solutions so far; specifically, it seems a little more general in that it doesn't assign a specific value for certain preimages. I'm still far from being comfortable with any of this stuff, though, so if I'm wrong on that point, please correct me. Anyway —

Because $U$ is a finite-dimensional subspace, it has a basis — call it $B=\left\{u_{1},u_{2},\ldots u_{r}\right\}$. Moreover, since $B$ is linearly independent in $V$, it can be expanded to a basis for $V$ — say, $B^{\prime}=\left\{ u_{1},\ldots u_{r},v_{r+1},\ldots v_{s}\right\}$. Since $B^{\prime}$ is also linearly independent, we can form a basis for another subspace, $V^{\prime}$, with the vectors in $B^{\prime}\backslash B=\left\{ v_{r+1},\ldots v_{s}\right\}$. Let $T^{\prime}\in\mathcal{L}\left(V^{\prime},W\right)$. Now we define $T:V\rightarrow W$ such that $T\left(v\right)=S\left(u\right)+T^{\prime}\left(v^{\prime}\right)$. Because $U$ and $\text{span}(B^{\prime}\backslash B)$ are subspaces of $V$, they both belong to $\mathcal{L}\left(V,W\right)$ as well; and since $\mathcal{L}\left(V,W\right)$ forms a vector space, $S+T^{\prime}=T$  is linear as well. Since each $u\in U$ can be written in $V$ as $a_{1}u_{i}+\ldots+a_{r}u_{r}+b_{r+1}v_{r+1}+\ldots+b_{s}v_{s}$, where $a_{i}\in\mathbb{F}$ and $b_{j}=0$, $T\left(u\right)=S\left(u\right)+T^{\prime}\left(0\right)=S\left(u\right)$.

Comment: But $S$ and $T'$ do not belong to $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ right? Since they are not functions defined on _all_ of $V$? But I think this should work when you extend $S$ and $T'$ to all of $V$ where the rest of the elements go to $0$ of $W$.

Answer (score 0):

I think that introducing the projection map is more intuitive. Given a vector space $V$, a linear map $P: V \to V$ is said to be a linear projection if $P^{2} = P$. As a consequence of this definition, given a subspace $U$ of $V$, there exists a linear projection $P:V \to V$ such that $P(V) = U$. To show this is not difficult, just consider $U'$ a linear complement of $U$, so $V = U\bigoplus U'$,  and given $v \in V$ we can express in a unique way $v = x + y$ where $x\in U$, $y\in V$; finally define $P(v) = x$ and show that $P$ is linear and $P^{2} = P$.

[image]

To answer the question, just define $T:V \to W$ as $T = S\circ P$. Note that $T(u) = S(u)$ for all $u \in U$.